# Cannot use more than 90 minutes in NUMTODSINTERVAL()

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a request that will compare the dates. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT f.Name,
       TO_CHAR(s.Film_Start_Time, 'hh24:mi'),
       TO_CHAR(f.Duration, 'hh24:mi'),
       f2.Name,
       TO_CHAR(s2.Film_Start_Time, 'hh24:mi'),
       TO_CHAR(f2.Duration, 'hh24:mi')
FROM   Schedule s
       JOIN Films f ON s.Film_Name = f.Name
       JOIN Schedule s2 ON s2.Film_Start_Time > s.Film_Start_Time
                       AND s2.Film_Start_Time < s.Film_Start_Time + NUMTODSINTERVAL(f.Duration, 'MINUTE')
       JOIN Films f2 ON s2.Film_Name = f2.Name
ORDER BY s.Film_Start_Time ASC;
```

But when value of f.Duration more than 90 minutes its crushed with error ORA-01481: invalid number format model
[Start time data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECTon.png)

Comment: please, put the sample data as text, not as an image.

Comment: Your image shows a `start_time` column - your code refers to `duration` and `film_start_time`. How are those three things related? Please include DDL (so we can see the data types) and sample data from both tables, and expected results for that data.

Comment: If `duration` is a date (?) then the `numtodsinterval()` call has to do an implicit conversion of that date to a number - which doesn't make sense. Your insert statements also don't work as they try to give  a number (e.g. 155) where  a date is expected.

Comment: Sorry wrong ddl. Duration is number

Comment: Understand the problem

Comment: OK, then `TO_CHAR(f.Duration, 'hh24:mi')` doesn't make sense... that's what's throwing the error, not the `numtodsinterval()` call.

Comment: Ye I forgot to remove it after changing the data type.  Strange that worked with 90 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `duration` column should be a `NUMBER` and not a `DATE`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE films (
    name             VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    duration         NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL,
    category         VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    company          VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
    country          VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
    year_of_release  NUMBER
);
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT f.Name,
       TO_CHAR(s.Film_Start_Time, 'hh24:mi') AS f1_start_time,
       TO_CHAR(s.film_start_time + NUMTODSINTERVAL(f.Duration, 'MINUTE'), 'hh24:mi')
         AS f1_end_time,
       f2.Name,
       TO_CHAR(s2.Film_Start_Time, 'hh24:mi') AS f2_start_time,
       TO_CHAR(s2.Film_start_time + NUMTODSINTERVAL(f2.Duration, 'MINUTE'), 'hh24:mi')
         AS f2_end_time
FROM   Schedule s
       JOIN Films f ON s.Film_Name = f.Name
       JOIN Schedule s2 ON s2.Film_Start_Time > s.Film_Start_Time
                       AND s2.Film_Start_Time < s.Film_Start_Time + NUMTODSINTERVAL(f.Duration, 'MINUTE')
       JOIN Films f2 ON s2.Film_Name = f2.Name
ORDER BY s.Film_Start_Time ASC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e40ec0038568e7adc58156a79f2db27)*